# How this guy goes from a equation to another equation

Tags: calculus

Can someone explain me how this guy from this (correct answer) [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506706/how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-points-with-polar-coordinates), goes from this equation:

$$x=r\cos \theta$$
To this equation?:
$$dx=dr\cos \theta-r\sin \theta d\theta$$
I can't understand it, i need the step by step, i'm still not good at calculus and i'm stubborn, so everything has to make sense to me, otherwise i don't understand...

Comment: Its just the product rule for differentiation $ \frac{d\left( f(x). g(x)\right)}{dx} = g\frac{df}{dx} + f\frac{dg}{dx}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
x&=r\cos\theta\\
\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(x\right)&=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(r\cos\theta\right)\\
\frac{dx}{d\theta}&=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta+r(-\sin\theta)\tag1\\
dx&=dr\cos\theta-r\sin\theta\,d\theta\tag2
\end{align}

In $(1)$, we use the product rule of differentiation $$y=fg\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=f'g+fg'$$ and in $(2)$, we treat the differential *like a fraction* by "multiplying through by $d\theta$".